# Deploying existing local project to Bluemix BuildPack error

Tags: php, deployment, command-line, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I hope someone can help me out with this issue I'm facing. 
I've made a fully functional project on a local server and would now like to deploy it to Bluemix Cloud Foundry.

I've followed the tutorial: https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/starters/upload_app.html

But when I'm trying to push it through terminal with following commands

```
cf push app_name -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2
cf push app_name -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack
cf push app_name -c start_command
cf push app_name -m 512m
```

But non seems to work, since every single time I get the following error

```
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
-----> Composer command failed

FAILED
Error restarting application: BuildpackCompileFailed
```

It is a PHP app build with PHPStorm on Symfony and Doctrine if that matters.
I am fairly new to all server/setup/deployment configurations as well as command line.

**EDIT 1**
I figured out this part thanks to this link: https://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/109600943-cf-push-ing-a-symfony-app-fails-with-Composer-command-failed-

It seems that by default the buildpack assumes that you want all of the files you push to be public.  Because of this assumption, it takes all of your files and moves them into the doc root of either HTTPD or Nginx.

By creating the file `.bp-config/options.json` in the root of your project.  Then inside options.json add

```
{
  "WEBDIR": "web"
}
```

This will tell the buildpack that you have a specific directory to use for the doc root, so it will just use that instead of moving everything into the default doc root.

However...
This brings me a new issue and returns the following error

```
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful
```

If i enter the recent log the terminal provides me this:

```
2016-08-25T02:53:40.62+0200 [App/0]      OUT Could not open input file: app.php
2016-08-25T02:53:40.62+0200 [App/0]      ERR 
2016-08-25T02:53:40.69+0200 [DEA/211]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-08-25T02:53:40.72+0200 [API/9]      OUT App instance exited with guid abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a", "version"=>"b6c3c871-5484-4f12-9d84-657cf6eacfbf", "instance"=>"c11566bdabe5458d9bfc4965c9c1aa85", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1472086420}
2016-08-25T02:53:40.72+0200 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a", "version"=>"b6c3c871-5484-4f12-9d84-657cf6eacfbf", "instance"=>"c11566bdabe5458d9bfc4965c9c1aa85", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1472086420}
2016-08-24T16:41:14.03+0200 [DEA/135]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a
2016-08-24T16:41:26.26+0200 [App/0]      ERR bash: start_command: command not found
2016-08-24T16:41:26.26+0200 [App/0]      OUT 
2016-08-24T16:41:26.35+0200 [DEA/135]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-08-24T16:41:26.38+0200 [API/6]      OUT App instance exited with guid abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"abb206b3-b8ea-4269-b248-ec7b35f7098a", "version"=>"5ebd6d77-68c4-4901-b9a8-b5cecfa4cddb", "instance"=>"7b5b555ae68645f4a2c09b73c0adbcb3", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1472049686}
```

**EDIT 2 (updated error msg)**

Comment: Is there any output before the `Staging failed` part? Usually when errors of this type occur, it's because your app is not packaged in a form that the PHP buildpack understands.

Comment: I found a continuos error saying `OUT Could not open input file: app.php` Could it be due to some restrictions set by Symfony or..?